# What is the meaning of a struct variable's name?

Tags: c++, c

What is the meaning of the struct variable's name?

In other words, when i tried code :

```
typedef struct enr
{
   int a ;
   char b ;
}enr ;

int main()
{
    enr x ;
    printf(" x = %d\n",x) ;
    printf(" x.a = %d\n",x.a);
    return 0 ;
}
```

I get : **38** for **x** and **a.x** both ! so I get the first field of the structure as a content of x.

Can any one tell me what's happen in the general case *(when the first variable was an array, char, or something else)*?

Comment: There is no such thing as C/C++, please choose in what language you need the answer.

Comment: There is no `a.x`, did you mean `x.a`? Please provide a _working example_ and not some pseudo-code which doesn't reproduce the issue.

Comment: You invoked *undefined behavior* for passing data having wrong type to `printf()`. Another *undefined behavior* will be invoked for using value of uninitialized variable having automatic storage duration, which is indeterminate, if you are using C.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`enr` is never initialized in your code, so the values of `a` and `b` are whatever happened to be in the memory before the object was constructed there. To fix this, use

```
enr x = {1, 'a'};
```

You get 38 in both case, because your `struct` is a POD - plain old data. Therefore, there is nothing more to you `struct` than an `int` and a `char` together. Because C++ does not reorder `struct` elements, the `struct` x is at the same address in memory as its first element, `x.a`. So when you `printf` them, you print the very same piece of memory.

Note that printing the struct type (`printf(" x = %d\n",x)`) via `%d` is technically undefined behaviour (by definition of `printf`). You get the same results here because `enr` is a POD and the compiler can somehow work around with that.

Another side note: In C++ a `struct` is a named type. So it is enough to just write `struct enr {...}`; The `typedef` you used is an old C-style.

Comment: So with enr defined as above, both statements will print out 1?

Comment: @mdewit It is still undefined behavior as `x` is not an `int`.

Comment: @mdewit Yes, [class.mem].13

Answer (score 2):

C has no knowledge of structure member types at runtime. But you *told* it what the type was with the `"%d"` in your `printf`. It printed the value of the integer at `x.a` not because `a` was declared to be an integer, but because you told it to. Likewise, `x` without the member refers to the structure as a whole, but since its address is the same as the address of its first member, and you told it to look for an `int` there, it found one. If your `printfs` had used `"%f"`, it would have printed a floating point number represented by the bits at that address for both expressions.

Comment: It would be nice to mention that all of this besides printing `x.a` is undefined behavior.

Comment: True, but many such undefined behaviors are actually pretty predictable with real-world compilers.

Comment: but why when i change the type of the first member, i have a difference between x and x.a ?